# IntelliJ Recompiling classes it could get from target/

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a multi-module project that uses maven. Is there a way I can point IntelliJ to maven target/ folder so when I start Debug it won't rebuild the project from scratch and re-upload a whole project via JRebel all over again.

Basically, use target/ as a build folder. Changing compile output path didn't work as I expected it to not compile classes that were compiled by mvn already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IntelliJ Run/Debug configurations can specify which actions happen before launching the application.

By default for say web applications, this would display

- Build
- Build x artifact

You may remove both entries if you are happy with building via maven before launching the application.

Regarding the JRebel side of it - it should certainly not be updating the classes on the second compile assuming nothing changed. The classes have their hashes checked before a reload. This is assuming maven and IntelliJ are using the default javac compiler. If either is configured to use ecj compiler, it's best to let JRebel only see classes built with the same compiler.